# WireFrame Mode is missing when hitting ctrl + tab

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, wireframe

I was doing the holy donut tutorial and suddenly when I select an object and use the shortcut
ctrl + tab, I don't see an option for wireframe mode, but earlier I remember it used to be there.

I don't think it has anything to do with OS because I didn't update anything or rebooted.
this problem occurred opening blender after closing it.

I can still use wireframe mode through click those spheres but still i want to know if there's any fix.

I am Using Blender 2.83
Os :- Linux Mint 19.3

Thank you

Attaching an image-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "shift + Z" to jump between solid mode and wireframe mode. "Z" to change between wireframe, solid, material preview, and rendered modes.

Hope it helped.

Comment: yea this was definitely helped. Thanks